# [Webpack]: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader

I use React+Webpack. I got the error, `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` After it, `SyntaxError: Unexpected token at ../../acorn.js.`

Why is it related to acorn.js? Also, I don't how to solve it. I think I already installed loaders that I needed. `webpack.config.dev.js` is working well, but when trying building `webpack.config.prod.js` I got this error.

Let me show my codes...

webpack.config.prod.js

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css']
    },
    {
      test: /\.png$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
    },
    {
      test: /\.jpg$/,
      loader: "file-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
    },
    {
      test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
    },
    {
      test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'file'
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
    },
    {
      test: /\.gif$/i,
      loaders: [
        'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
        'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.json?$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }
  ]
},

resolve: {
  root: [
    path.resolve('./src'),
    path.resolve('./style')
  ],
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
},

plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    tempalte: './public/index.html'
  }),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env':{
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  }),
],
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
  "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
  "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
  "image-webpack-loader": "^3.2.0",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
  "webpack": "^1.12.9",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.15.3",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "lodash": "^4.17.4",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "react": "^15.4.2",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
  "react-bootstrap-table": "^3.1.7",
  "react-dnd": "^2.2.3",
  "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.2.3",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
  "react-js-pagination": "^2.0.2",
  "react-modal": "^1.7.3",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
  "react-router": "^3.0.2",
  "react-slick": "0.14.5",
  "react-toastr": "^2.8.2",
  "redux": "^3.6.0",
  "redux-form": "^6.5.0",
  "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
  "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0"
}
```

Comment: Don't think it's the loader. It probably breaks on that acorn.js. That your loader fails, is a consequence of that. I don't see anything resembling acorn.js in your package? Have you installed it?

Comment: @stevenvanc when `npm install`, acorn.js is installed, but i don't know why it is installed

Comment: Your loader only transpiles `.jsx` files, try `/\.jsx?$/,` for babel loader

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri You're right. I now understand and solve the problem... Thank you!

Comment: I added it as an answer since it solved you issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module loader only transpile the `.jsx` files, change the test expression to transpile the `.js` files as well

```
loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    },
```